# Adding more than 1 content with ::after?

Tags: css, font-awesome, pseudo-element

I'm trying to understand the CSS selector `::after` and `::before`.

```
.h2 a:before{
    content: "\f0c1";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

This adds a FontAwesome icon if said header is a link. However, I'd like to add an empty space *after* adding this icon. Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: `content: "\f0c1 ";`

Comment: Omg....It's too early for me ... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do with "margin-right" property